# Passing array of pointers to a function accepting 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, output

I have the following code in C

```c
#include <stdio.h>
 
char *gstr[] = { "Hello", "World" };
 
void func(char str[][8]) {
    printf("%p\n", (void *)str);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)(str + 1));
    printf("%s\n", *(str + 1));
}
 
int main(void) {
    printf("%p\n", (void *)gstr);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)(gstr + 1));
    printf("%s\n", *(gstr + 1));
 
    printf("Calling Function\n");
 
    func(gstr);
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the output

```
0x556f11ddd010
0x556f11ddd018
World
Calling Function
0x556f11ddd010
0x556f11ddd018
$��oU
```

I cannot understand why `printf("%s\n", *(str+1));` in the function `func` does not print the string `world`.

Comment: What made you choose the prototype `void func(char str[][8])`? How did you compile your code - did you receive any warnings?

Comment: If using `gcc` for example, compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -g` and resolve any errors that show. You can't expect a certain behavior when you run invalid code

Comment: If you compile if with the command I suggested, you will see the error immediately: `incompatible pointer type ... expected ‘char (*)[8]’ but argument is of type ‘char **’`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char *gstr[] = {"Hello", "World"};` declares `gstr` to be an array of pointers to `char`.

By itself, `char str[][8]` declares `str` to be an array of arrays of eight `char`. However, as a function parameter, it is automatically adjusted from an array to a pointer: It declares `str` to be a pointer to an array of eight `char`.

A pointer to an array is different from an array of pointers.

Your compiler should have warned you that the type of `gstr` in `func(gstr)` is incompatible with the type of the parameter in `void func(char str[][8])`. Pay attention to the messages from your compiler.

To pass `gstr` to `func` correctly, change the declaration of `func` to `func(char *str[])` or the equivalent `func(char **str)`.

`func(gstr)` passes the address of the first element of `gstr` to the function. Since `gstr` is an array of pointers, the address of its first element is the address of a pointer (that being a pointer to the first character of `"Hello"`).

In `func`, the function expects a pointer to an array of eight `char`. If it uses the address it is given for that, it is pointing to a pointer instead of an array of eight `char`. Passing that to `printf` attempts to print the bytes representing the pointer as if they were a string of characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the code below to see the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
char *gstr[] = {"Hello", "World"};
 
void func(char str[][8]) {
    printf("%p\n", (void*) str);
    printf("%p\n", (void*) *str);
    printf("%p\n", (void*) (str+1));
    printf("%p\n", (void*) *(str+1));
    printf("%s\n", *(str+1));
}
 
int main(void) {
    printf("%p\n", (void *) gstr);
    printf("%p\n", (void *) *gstr);
    printf("%p\n", (void*) (gstr+1));
    printf("%p\n", (void*) *(gstr+1));
    printf("%s\n", *(gstr+1));
 
    printf("Calling Function\n");
 
    func(gstr);
    return 0;
}
```

```
0x100402010
0x100403000
0x100402018
0x100403006
World
Calling Function
0x100402010
0x100402010
0x100402018
0x100402018
0@
```

The compiler know that gstr is an array of pointers, so that in function `main`, the object at `gstr + 1` will be interpreted as `char*` and you get the expected result.

However in function `func`, the bytes at `str + 1` will be interpreted as `char [8]`, and you know it will return the first address of this object which is `str+1`